# How to make superscript to be aligned to the top of last dot

Tags: css

[image: SuperScript]

How can I display superscript such that it is on the top of dot?
Code Here

```
<div >5.<sup>22</sup></div>
```

Comment: There may be several ways of accomplishing this, but I'd say that any of them that suggest using "px" rather than "em" units should be avoided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/eaqxcsbz/)

Okay. So I checked and the default formatting has two major problems.

The first is, that the `<sup>` follows the period, instead of being on top of it. The best way to solve this is probably a negative margin, as a relative position would leave a gap if there is more Text after that. If you use a relative size like `em` instead of `px` it will be easier to adjust if the sizes should ever change.

The next is to get the top of the normal text and the `<sup>` to align on top. The default `vertical-align` for `<sup>` is actually slightly above the top of the line, so resetting it to top almost gets you there.
Then tweaking the line-height to do the rest works just fine.

```
sup {
    margin-left: -0.25em;
    vertical-align: top;
    line-height: 1.1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well.. this works, but I believe someone will find a better answer:

```css
sup:before {
    content: '.';
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -7px; /* adjust with line-height */
    left: 0;
}

sup {
    position: relative;
    
}
```

```html
<div >5<sup>22</sup></div>
```

I think its a risk if your content is full dynamic, or if you have several line-heights. Anyways, adjust the bottom position with the line-height from the div.

Answer (score 0):

You can move the `<sup>` to the left like so:

```
sup {
    position: relative;
    left: -4px;
}
```